# update.packages() repeatedly asks me for EVERY package. How do I stop it?

Tags: r, updates

When running `update.packages()` in R how do I avoid answering *"do you want to update this package"* a hundred times?

`update.packages()` asks me *individually* if I want to update nearly every package I have with the prompt shown as `y/n/c`. I end up hitting <kbd>Y</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> repeatedly for five minutes. What does the "C" mean? Does it get me around this problem? I don't dare choose that option not knowing what it means. Y is obviously Yes and N is obviously No. C? Anybody's guess?

Comment: maybe you want to use the `ask` argument of `update.packages`?

Comment: Thank you, and out of curiosity what does the "C" mean in y/n/c?

Comment: "c" stands for `cancel` and would allow you to abort the whole operation

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See in the help for `update.packages` (`?update.packages`):

> ask:
> logical indicating whether to ask the user to select packages
> before they are downloaded and installed, or the character string
> "graphics", which brings up a widget to allow the user to (de-)select
> from the list of packages which could be updated. (The latter value
> only works on systems with a GUI version of select.list, and is
> otherwise equivalent to ask = TRUE.)

So the behaviour you are expecting can be accomplished with the following:

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE)
```

The `c` in `y/n/c` simply means **c**ancel and stops the update process completely. Another trick to speed things up is to set the number of cores used for installing packages: e.g., `update.packages(ask = FALSE, Ncpus = 3L)`.