# Error loading library tidyverse, dbplyr, ggplot2

Tags: r, package, tidyverse, dbplyr

I would like to install more packages in RStudio and got a error message. Before, I worked with `gglot2` and it worked well. When I tried to install other packages, more errors occure.

I loaded library `DBI`, `vctrs` without a problem, then I'm trying:

```
> library(ggplot2)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.4.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.0 is required

> library(tidyverse)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.4.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.1 is required

> library(lubridate)

> library(dbplyr)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dbplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘cli’ 3.2.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.3.0 is required
```

I checked all updates, restart R Studio, tried to update `vctrs`, but anything works. Could anyone help me?

Comment: what happens if you run `install.packages('vctrs')`?

Comment: @Phil It runs with warning:

Warning in install.packages :

  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘cli’
Warning in install.packages :
  problem copying C:\R\win-library\4.1\00LOCK\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll to C:\R\win-library\4.1\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll: Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
  restored ‘cli’
(the rest or error in next post)

Comment: package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘vctrs’
Warning in install.packages :
  problem copying C:\R\win-library\4.1\00LOCK\vctrs\libs\x64\vctrs.dll to C:\R\win-library\4.1\vctrs\libs\x64\vctrs.dll: Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
  restored ‘vctrs’

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have old versions of packages installed and loaded.

For example, you have a version of `vctrs` installed but `ggplot2` needs a more recent version. This is especially a problem if you have already called `library(vctrs)` because the active version of the package is already determined.

The simplest solution is to update your packages. Here are many questions on Stackoverflow about how to do that. Try some of the following links:

- [Update R using RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656699/update-r-using-rstudio)
- [How to update packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461649/how-to-update-a-package-in-r)
- [Update packages asks for every package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322634/update-packages-repeatedly-asks-me-for-every-package-how-do-i-stop-it)